# Why does this code cause an "ambiguous variable occurrence" error?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I wrote a function called `product`:

```
product [] = 1
product (x:xs) = x * product xs
```

When I load it into WinHug:

> ERROR file:.\product.hs:4 - Ambiguous variable occurrence "product"
>   *** Could refer to: Main.product Hugs.Prelude.product

What does this mean?

Answer (score 15):

The `product` function is [defined in the Haskell Prelude.](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:product)

Your local definition conflicts with the library version.

Consider renaming your version as e.g. `myproduct` or `import Prelude hiding (product)`.

Also, you might want to consider [using GHC instead of Hugs.](http://haskell.org/platform)

Answer (score 8):

There is already a function named [`product`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:product) in the [Haskell Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html).

By the way, you should install the [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) instead of Hugs; Hugs is an old project that is no longer being maintained, and GHC/i is far more well-supported and has more features. Even if your school wants you to use Hugs, it doesn't hurt to secretly use the Haskell Platform with GHCi in private.